# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting.(Armstrong number)

Tags: python, typeerror

```
n=input("enter the number: ")
num=n
digit,sum=0,0
length=len(str(n))
for i in range(length):
    digit=int(num%10)
    num=num/10
    sum+=pow(digit,length)
if sum==n:
    print("armstrong")
else: 
    print("Not armstrong")
```

when I run this code, it show error in line 6:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting>
```

the question is find the number is Armstrong or not.

Comment: Make `n` variable receive an integer input `n = int(input("enter the number: "))`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first convert the string into an integer before performing any mathematical operation.
Here is the revised code.

```py
n=input("enter the number: ")
num=n
digit,sum=0,0
length=len(str(n))
for i in range(length):
    digit=int(num)%10
    num=int(num)/10
    sum+=pow(digit,length)
if sum==n:
    print("armstrong")
else:
    print("Not armstrong")
```

Before using the num variable convert it to an int to avoid any error.